# Handling root directory/route in Express + Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using Express + Node JS with my site and I have been trying to handle users' requests of 'www.mysite.com/' or 'www.mysite.com' to redirect to 'www.mysite.com/dashboard'. Is this possible and if so how is it done?! I have the following in my routes file:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
});
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

do you assign the route for `/` BEFORE the route to `/dashboard` ?

Like this

```
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
});

app.get('/dashboard',function(req,res) {
    res.render('dashboard');
});
```

Comment: Here is my entry in the routes file:                   app.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, Dashboard.getHome);
 app.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.redirect('/dashboard');
 }); I still get a broken page.

Answer (score 0):

remove slash yes dashboard route also has to be define

```
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.redirect('dashboard');
});
```